# Is it possible to use splatting with a nested hashtable in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Example:

```
Get-Service -Name w*
$t = @{a = @{Name = 'w*'} }
```

The goal is to splat `$t.a` to `Get-Service`.

These do not work (some for obvious reasons):

```
Get-Service @t.a
Get-Service @(t.a)
Get-Service @($t.a)
Get-Service ($t.@a)
Get-Service $t.@a
```

The only workaround I could figure out so far is:

```
$b = $t.a
Get-Service @b
```

Comment: Is this another workaround? `$t.a | %{ Get-Process @_ }`

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so, no. Even if there is a way, using

```
$b = $t.a
Get-Service @b
```

is still a lot cleaner and what I would recommend.

Example of how to implement it:

```
function disableservices ($type) { 
    $types = @{
        web = @{name = '*iis*'}
        db = @{name = '*sqlserv*'}
        windows = @{name = 'win*' }
    }

    if($types.ContainsKey($type)) {
        $b = $types[$type]
        Get-Service @b | Stop-Service
    } else {
        Write-Error "The type '$type' is not supported"
    }
}

disableservices windows
```

Comment: I couldn't find a way around it either, but if that's the only option I think you'd be better off just starting with $b = @{Name = 'w*'}. Putting them all into and hash table first and then re-assigning every element to discrete variables seems kind of silly.

Comment: I would normally agree, but I could actually see the use of this. See example :)

Comment: Correct, there is no way to splat anything but a simple variable.