# Why do I need to splat to a variable first

Tags: powershell

In an attempt to clean up my coding style, I have been playing around with splatting (knowing how much the backtick is disliked) so we end up with something like this

```
$splat = @{
    "ResourceGroupName" = $ResourceGroupName
    "Location" = $location
    "WhatIf" = $true 
    "ErrorVariable" = "err"
    "ErrorAction" = "SilentlyContinue"
}
New-ResourceGroup @splat
```

Which has always felt unnatural to me, I don't like that the parameters are coming before the cmdlet. It irks me!

So I am curious why this can't / doesn't work. (and whether it can be made to do so)

```
New-ResourceGroup @{
    "ResourceGroupName" = $ResourceGroupName
    "Location" = $location
    "WhatIf" = $true 
    "ErrorVariable" = "err"
    "ErrorAction" = "SilentlyContinue"
}
```

Which to me feels a lot more natural. Is there a way to do this? or am I forever doomed to putting the cart before the horse...

**edited to add**

In case there isn't an answer to this, I have posted a [Uservoice](http://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/11708589-allow-splatting-without-an-intermediate-variable) suggestion - feel free to go and vote for it.

Comment: I wish that worked, too.

Comment: @MikeShepard I'm glad I'm not the only one! I'm just hoping one of the Powershell geniuses here gives us a D'er! that's easy...

Comment: FWIW, you can lose the quotes in your hashes.  Since parameter names don't have spaces the quotes aren't needed.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible AFAIK. The problem is the `@splat` isn't simply passing an hashtable (which is a single value). Unlike `$` which simply reads the variable, the splatting-operator `@` splits the single object (collection) and matches it to the parameters. Also, the splatting-operator cannot be used for anything else than passing parameter values.

```
PS C:\Users\frode> @splat
At line:1 char:1
+ @splat
+ ~~~~~~
The splatting operator '@' cannot be used to reference variables in an expression. '@splat' can be used only a
s an argument to a command. To reference variables in an expression use '$splat'
```

Because of this, we can't use it in a subexpression (ex. `dir @(@{ Filter = "notepad.exe" })` ) or something similar to be able to create the hashtable directly in the cmdlet-call.

I agree that this would be great and I would recommend submitting a feature requst on [PowerShell @ UserVoice](http://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869). Creating the hashtable upfront is still a small price to pay to get more readable scripts.

Comment: Connect migrated to [UserVoice](http://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869).

Comment: This is pretty much what I'd figured! the @(@{ was my first attempt at hacking it! I'm still going to hope that you're wrong though

Comment: Good call. :) Updated

Comment: Went looking for a dupe and I found Frode again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22692048/is-it-possible-to-use-splatting-with-a-nested-hashtable-in-powershell. It would appear you havent figured it out after all the time :)

Comment: Haha.. Look at that ! :D

Answer (score 0):

[TesselatingHacker presents another potential workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22692048/is-it-possible-to-use-splatting-with-a-nested-hashtable-in-powershell?lq=1#comment34577291_22692048) that isn't half bad. Pass the hashtable to the pipeline and splat the pipeline object to the cmdlet/function.

```
@{
    Filter = "*.txt"
    Path = "d:\temp"
    File = $true
} | ForEach-Object{Get-ChildItem @_}
```

Still easy to read and still retains readability. If you would prefer the `ForEach-Object` alias `%` would make that more terse.

Comment: I like it (when using `%`), but unfortunately you still have to specify parameters "outside" the cmdlet, and you loose pipeline-support, ex: `$t = @{ Raw = $true }; dir "*.txt" | Get-Content @t`

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a great solution. You can create a function that takes the original command and runs it after it splats the arguments that you designate.

```
// Used for getting splatted arguments
function Arguments { $args }

// Takes a command, splats all arguments preceded by '-Splat', then runs the command using the splatted arguments
function Splat {
    $_command, $_args = @($args)
    $_input = @($input)
    $_args = $_args | % { $Previous = $Current; $Current = $_; $_ } | % { $_ -eq '-Splat' ? @() : $Previous -eq '-Splat' ? (Arguments @_) : (, $_) }
    $_input | & $_command @_args
}
```

So now you can do this:

```
Splat New-ResourceGroup -Splat @{
    "ResourceGroupName" = $ResourceGroupName
    "Location" = $location
    "WhatIf" = $true 
    "ErrorVariable" = "err"
    "ErrorAction" = "SilentlyContinue"
}
```

Or with multiple splats:

```
1,2,3 | Splat MyCommand 'a1' -Arg2 'a2' -Splat @{Arg3='a3'; Arg4='a4'} 'a5' -Splat @(
'a6', 'a7') -Splat (CommandReturningHashtable)
```

... just make sure none of your commands happen to also have a param named 'Splat'.